# If-statement never reaches the else part

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the text of a button with the following code.

```
// hide unavailable courses
$("#availability_button").click(function () {
    $(".availability_red").toggle();
        if ($(this).val('Show Unavailable')){
            $(this).html('Hide Unavailable');
        } else {
            $(this).html('Show Unavailable');
        }
});
```

The button text changes the first time I use it, but never again. Not sure why that is and I have pretty much hit the limits of my JS debugging knowledge.

I put an alert into it and proved it never reaches down to the else path.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When you pass an argument to `.val`, it will return a jQuery object, which always evaluates to `true`. Please refer to the documentation for the usage of `.val`: http://api.jquery.com/val/.

Comment: you're using .val as a setter instead of a getter with comparison.

Comment: If it never enter on else block it's because the if block always evaluates to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always evaluates to `true` because `.val(val)` returns the jQuery object and objects are truthy (`ToBoolean` gives `true`) values.

Also, you are using `.val()` whereas you probably want to check the `.html()`

Try this:

```
if ($(this).html() === 'Show Unavailable') {
    $(this).html('Hide Unavailable');
} else {
    $(this).html('Show Unavailable');
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/jfetf/

Answer (score 3):

`$(this).val("Show Unavailable")` is setting the value and returning an object, it's not checking equality.

Try `$(this).val() == "Show Unavailable"` instead. It will take the current value and compare it to the string.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val('Show Unavailable')` return `jQuery object` which is interprete as `true`.

Also $(this).val('Show Unavailable') set value to element...